# Compute $H_{*}(M, \mathbb{Z})$ of gluing 2 solid tori.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, knot-theory

Let $M$ be the space obtained by gluing two solid tori $D^2 \times S^1$ and $S^1 \times D^2$ together via the identity map of their boundaries. Compute $H_{*}(M, \mathbb{Z}.)$

**A Hint:**

Use Mayer Vietoris and this is called Handle Body Decomposition. Still I am stucked in  writing the details of the solution, could anyone help me in doing so please?

Answer (score 3):

$\require{AMScd}$

The space $P=(S^1\times D^2)\cup_{S^1\times S^1}(D^2\times S^1)$ we are interested in gluing together is that obtained as the pushout in the next square
\begin{CD}
    S^1\times S^1 @>\subseteq >> S^1\times D^2\\
    @V\subseteq V V   @VVV\\
    D^2\times S^1 @>>> P.
\end{CD}
Since each of the indicated inclusions is a closed embedding (they are closed cofibrations), the triad $(P;S^1\times D^2,D^2\times S^1)$ is excisive and we get a Mayer-Vietoris sequence

$$\dots \rightarrow H_*(S^1\times S^1)\xrightarrow{i_{1*}-i_{2*}} H_*(S^1\times D^2)\oplus H_*(D^2\times S^1)\xrightarrow{j_{1*}+j_{2*}} H_*P\xrightarrow{\Delta} H_{*-1}(S^1\times S^1)\rightarrow \dots$$

where the maps $i_1,i_2,j_1,j_2$ are the inclusions defined by the above square (although I have not labeled them in it), and $\Delta$ is the connecting map granted by the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

Now $S^1\times S^1$, $S^1\times D^2$ and $D^2\times S^1$ are all path connected, so therefore so is $P$. Thus in degree $0$ we have a split exact sequence

$$0\rightarrow H_0(S^1\times S^1)\xrightarrow{i_{1*}-i_{2*}} H_0(S^1\times D^2)\oplus H_0(D^2\times S^1)\xrightarrow{j_{1*}+j_{2*}} H_0P\rightarrow 0$$

and we can focus on the higher degree homology below. Now

$$H_1(S^1\times S^1)\cong\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z},\qquad H_1(S^1\times D^2)\cong\mathbb{Z},\qquad H_1(D^2\times S^1)\cong\mathbb{Z}.$$

The first group we can get by applying the Kunneth formula. The second two groups we can get by the homotopy invariance of homology by contracting the discs: $S^1\times D^2\simeq S^1\simeq D^2\times S^1$.

The point is that not only does the Kunenth formula compute the group, but it tells us exactly what the generators of it are, namely the homology cross products $s_1\times 1$ and $1\times s_1$ of the two copies of your favourite generators $s_1\in H_1S^1$.

Comparing the two methods of computing the groups above we see that the composite

$$H_1(S^1\times S^1)\xrightarrow{i_{1*}} H_1(S^1\times D^2)\cong H_1S^1$$

coincides with the map induced by projection

$$pr_1:H_1(S^1\times S^1)\rightarrow H_1S^1$$

and this map satisfies $pr_{1*}(s_1\times 1)=s_1$, $pr_{1*}(1\times s_1)=0$. Identical anaylsis gives similar results for the other map $i_{2*}$.

Returning to the Mayer-Vietoris sequence we have

$$\dots\rightarrow H_2(P)\xrightarrow\Delta H_1(S^1\times S^1)\xrightarrow{i_{1*}-i_{2*}} H_1(S^1\times D^2)\oplus H_1(D^2\times S^1)\xrightarrow{j_{1*}+j_{2*}} H_1P\rightarrow 0.$$

The right-hand map is onto by our analysis above of $H_0$. The argument presented above is that $i_{1*}-i_{2*}$ is injective, and identifies with the map

$$H_1(S^1\times S^1)\cong\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\ni (a,b)\mapsto (a,-b)\in \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\cong H_1(S^1\times S^2)\oplus H_1(D^2\times S^1).$$

But this map is an isomorphism. Hence $j_{1*}+j_{2*}=0$ by exactness, and

$$H_1P=0.$$

We also get from exactness that the map $\Delta$ in the above sequence is trivial. Now

$$H_2(S^1\times S^1)\cong\mathbb{Z},\qquad H_n(S^1\times S^1)=0,\quad n\geq3$$

since $S^1\times S^1$ is an orientable $2$-manifold (or just use Kunneth again), and

$$H_n(S^1\times D^2)\cong H_n(D^2\times S^1)\cong H_nS^1=0,\quad n\geq 2$$

the Mayer-Vietoris sequence in degree $2$ degenerates into an isomorphism

$$0\rightarrow H_3P\xrightarrow{\Delta} H_2(S^1\times S^1)\rightarrow 0$$

and this is the top degree in which there is homology. Summarising, we have that

$$H_*P\cong\begin{cases}\mathbb{Z}&\ast=0\\
\mathbb{Z}&\ast=3.\end{cases}$$

Which is exactly what we would expect, really, since $P\cong S^3$. What we have is a rather special form of handle decomposition, reserved for $3$-dimensional manifolds, which is usually called a *Heegaard splitting*.

Comment: why we stopped at $n = 3$?

Comment: why $i_{1_{*}} - i_{2_{*}}$ while  $j_{1_{*}} + j_{2_{*}}$?

Comment: The diagram contain 2 inclusion maps while Mayer Vietoris contains 4 ..... could you please explain this?

Comment: Why $H_{0}(P) = Z$?

Comment: 1) Because of exactness. We know that $H_n(S^1\times S^1)=0$ for $n\geq3$ and $H_n(S^1\times D^2)\cong H_n(D^2\times S^1)=0$ for $n\geq2$.

Comment: 2) Because the minus sign appears in the maps in the Mayer-Vietoris sequence. See Hatcher, pg. 150, for instance. The sign flip makes the sequence exact.

Comment: 3) The pushout of a (closed) embedding is a (closed) embedding (feel free to prove this yourself). This means that the maps $D^2\times S^1\rightarrow P$ and $S^1\times D^2\rightarrow P$ in the pushout square are closed embeddings (aka closed inclusions).

Comment: 4) Since $S^1\times S^1$ is path connected you can apply $\pi_0$ to the pushout square to get a pushout of sets. Since $S\times D^2$ and $D^2\times S^1$ are path connected, you conclude that $\pi_0P$ is a singleton. This is a version of the seifert-van Kampen Theorem. You know that $H_0$ of a space is the free abelian group on its path components (Hatcher, Pr. 2.7, pg. 109).

Comment: Can you please  explain my last question using homology groups ..... I know that $H_{0}(S^1 \times S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$ and I know that $H_{0}(S^1 \times D^2) \oplus H_{0}(D^2 \times S^1) = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$  but then what should I do to know $H_{0}(P)$?

Comment: Are we using the first isomorphism theorem in that step?

Comment: @Mathstupid, I did try to explain it in terms of homlogy groups. Did you look at Hatcher, Pr. 2.7, pg. 109? You can calculate $H_0P$ by calculating its set of path components $\pi_0P$. You can do this explicitly by using the standard definition of the pushout space. You just need to show that $H_0(D^2\times S^1)\oplus H_0(S^1\times D^2)\rightarrow H_0P$ is surjective: so pick a cycle representing a class $H_0P$ and show that it comes from a cycle in the other group.

Comment: Then we will use the first isomorphism theorem?

Comment: So we just use proposition 2.7 as we are in a case of path connected space then $H_{0} = \mathbb{Z}$ without first isomorphism theorem or anything?

Comment: can you please include the details of showing that this map is surjective in your answer ?

Comment: Sorry I did not get what you said about $H_{0}$ before you said this "Returning to the Mayer-Vietoris sequence we have

$$\dots\rightarrow H_2(P)\xrightarrow\Delta H_1(S^1\times S^1)\xrightarrow{i_{1*}-i_{2*}} H_1(S^1\times D^2)\oplus H_1(D^2\times S^1)\xrightarrow{j_{1*}+j_{2*}} H_1P\rightarrow 0.$$

The right-hand map is onto by our analysis above of $H_0$ " could you summarize it please?  ...... Also after that I did not understand what you are doing?

Comment: I see how the RHS map is onto now sorry

Comment: 1) No. 2) Yes. 3) I can edit in the content of my last couple of comments. 4) I mean look at the sequence in degree $0$. 5) No worries. I hope everything is clear now?

Comment: I did not get how because $i_{1_{*}} - i_{2_{*}}$ is an isomorphism then    $j_{1_{*}} + j_{2_{*}}$  is zero by exactness .... could you please explain this ?

Comment: By exactness $\ker(j_{1*}+j_{2*})=im(i_{1*}-i_{2*})=$ entire group since an isomorphism is onto.

Comment: Is your calculation for $H_{2}(P)$ is by the same argument followed in  $H_{1}(P)$?

Comment: I think it is simpler as it is coming out of zero and entering into 0 ..... am I correct?

Comment: Since $i_{1*}-i_{2*}$ is injective in degree $1$ we have $im(H_2P\xrightarrow\Delta H_1S^1\times S^1)=0$. Thus $H_2P$ is a quotient of $H_2(S^1\times D^2)\oplus H_2(D^2\times S^1)=0$.